# oracle forms and reports console unable to display, during verifying the installation

Tags: weblogic, oracleforms

i was installing oracle softwares,weblogic server 12.2.1.4 and oracle forms and reports 12.2.1.4 on my server. The installation was successful for both products(no errors) but when i try to verify the installation using http://host:port/forms/frmservlet and http://host:port/reports/rwservlet there was no display.

any idea what could be the problem

still new in oracle technologies.

Comment: Is WebLogic server up and running? And ensure, Forms and Reports services are running by login to WebLogic console.

Comment: Yaa, i have started the server and both OEM and weblogic consoles are fine. The reports and forms serving are up and running.